# SwiftUI: Cannot find 'systemName' in scope

Tags: swift, swiftui

This seems like really easy to fix, But I can't get my head around it.

How can i show SFSymbols' `shift.fill` if the list of upvoters contain `Foo` and if not, show `shift`

```
Image(aQuestion.upVoters.contains(where: {$0 == "Foo"}) ? systemName:"shift.fill": systemName:"shift")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. When using the `?` operator to pass different values to an input parameter based on a `Bool`, you always need to put the ternary expression **after** the input argument label and only write out the label once.

```
Image(systemName: aQuestion.upVoters.contains(where: {$0 == "Foo"}) ? "shift.fill": "shift")
```